# How can I use GetPlan service in Python?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to use **make_plan** service of **move_base** package in order to create a path towards a specified goal. How am i supposed to deal with this service in ***Python*** ?

```
    start = PoseStamped()
    start.header.seq = 0
    start.header.frame_id = "map"
    start.header.stamp = rospy.Time(0)
    start.pose.position.x = robot_x  #2.6
    start.pose.position.y = robot_y  #1.3

    Goal = PoseStamped()
    Goal.header.seq = 0
    Goal.header.frame_id = "map"
    Goal.header.stamp = rospy.Time(0)
    Goal.pose.position.x = goal_x  #-6.2
    Goal.pose.position.y = goal_y  #-3.0
    
    srv = GetPlan()
    srv.request.start = start
    srv.request.goal = Goal
    srv.request.tolerance = 1.5
```

I assume that in this way I can declare the robot's current position(start) and target's coordinates(goal) as presented [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetPlan.html). In which way should I ***initialize the server*** so that i can obtain the path ? What's the crucial part that I have to add in my code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330609/how-can-i-use-getplan-service-in-python-?/) by [Dimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44686/dimi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you have to call the service:

```
get_plan = rospy.ServiceProxy('/move_base/make_plan', nav_msgs.GetPlan)
req = nav_msgs.GetPlan()
req.start = start
req.goal = Goal
req.tolerance = .5
resp = get_plan(req.start, req.goal, req.tolerance)
print(resp)
```

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44686/dimi/) on 2019-08-13**:
Thanks, indeed. Just to point out that I need to modify the last line :

```
resp = get_plan(req)
```

to :

```
resp = get_plan(req.start, req.goal, req.tolerance)
```

otherwise I get an error !

**Comment by [LukeBowersox](https://answers.ros.org/users/53108/lukebowersox/) on 2020-04-14**:
I followed  ct2304's advice in ros kinetic and it worked also I had to import nav_msgs.srv